# Bash script "mv" makes a copy?

Tags: bash, mv

I'm writing my first Bash script and this puzzles me:

```
sdir="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"

echo "... downloading skeleton ..."
  wget -q -P $sdir --no-check-certificate https://github.com/xxx/master.zip
  unzip -q $sdir/master.zip -d $sdir
  rm -f $sdir/master.zip
echo "... downloading finished ..."
  mv $sdir/Unzipped-master-folder $sdir/master
echo "... created new dir mdir/ ..."
```

I'm downloading zipped master, unzip it in my source dir (which creates a folder "Unzipped-master-folder"). When I want to rename it to "master" with mv, I get a new folder "master" but the old one still remains, as if mv copied and forgot to clean up.

I already inserted a 5 second sleep delay before mv is executed, but to no avail.

**EDIT: Nevermind, stupid mistake on my part, where further down in the script, I copied the folder into the dir again. mv works as expected and removes old folder.**

Comment: When you say the old one remains do you mean just the directory or the file as well? I thought that was normal behaviour if only the directory is left and you just need a rm $sdir/Unzipped-master-folder

Comment: try to add "set -x" as your first line to enable bash debug and rerun the script

Comment: @PeterJ The old folder complete with content remains. What I don't understand is, that if I use `mv` on Terminal, it always removes the old file/folder automatically. Not the same for you?

Comment: @dAm2K Thanks for the debbuging line! Paths are fine though.

Comment: Don't forget to put `"` around your variables, as in `rm -f "$sdir/master.zip"`. This prevents bad stuff from happening if they contain spaces etc.

Comment: Been a while since I've done it, so my comment on mv was going from vague memory but thought it was good to clarify anyway for anyone else that comes along anyway.

Comment: @PeterJ Stupid mistake on my part. `mv` does remove the old file/folder alright.